# VHDL: I have a lot of inferring latches due to my case statement

Tags: vhdl, latch

I have coded a project for an FPGA and in one of my files which is a mux, I have a lot of inferring latches, which I think is due to my case statement.
The code looks like this:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

entity twoplayermux1 is
    port
    (
        --inputs:
        show                 :  in std_logic;
        set              : in std_logic;
        input                : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        try                  : in std_logic;
        player               : in std_logic;

        --outputs:
        show_out             : out std_logic;
        set_out          : out std_logic;
        input_out        : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        try_out          : out std_logic;

        show_out2        : out std_logic;
        set_out2             : out std_logic;
        input_out2       : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        try_out2             : out std_logic
    );
end twoplayermux1;

architecture Behavioral of twoplayermux1 is
begin

process (show,set,input,try,player)

begin

case(player) is
        when '0' =>
            show_out <= show;           
            set_out <= set;
            input_out <= input;
            try_out <= try;
        when '1' =>
            show_out2 <= show;          
            set_out2 <= set;
            input_out2 <= input;
            try_out2 <= try;
        when others =>
            null;
        end case;

    end process twoplayermux1;

end Behavioral;
```

What could be the reason I get these latches?

Comment: Your 'others' section does not assign any values. I suggest you go to stackexchange and search for 'latches' there are dozens of equivalent questions and answers there.

Comment: @Oldfart
Is that the only reason or are there other reasons?

Comment: In a combinatorial section every variable has be assigned a value for every possible path.  If not, you get a latch. I can write a full answer but this question has been answered to death already in stackexchange (And I am not desperate for points.)

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that the logic doesn't describe a mux at all. You're sending one set of inputs to two possible destinations, which is the opposite of a mux — a demux.

A `case` statement is not the appropriate construct to use. Instead, you need a series of statements of the form:

```
architecture Behavioral of twoplayermux1 is
begin
    show_out   <= show  when player = '0' else '0';
    set_out    <= set   when player = '0' else '0';
    input_out  <= input when player = '0' else "00000000";
    -- etc.

    show_out2  <= show  when player = '1' else '0';
    set_out2   <= set   when player = '1' else '0';
    input_out2 <= input when player = '1' else "00000000";
    -- etc.

end Behavioral;
```

I'm just guessing about what you want in the `else` clauses — you could put other values there.

Comment: Is your example a with-select assignment?

Comment: No. Just ordinary continuous assignment statements.

Comment: If I delete the case statement and everything else in-between "begin" and "end process twoplayermux1", and I replace the previous with your example it gives me errors. How exactly does the syntax look like?

Comment: I have implemented your example by using an if else statement, but the compilation output in Quartus still tells me that I have a lot of inferring latches.

Comment: No, these statements do not go inside a process. They are just part of the architecture body. See edit above,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take this as a little additional explanation.
The root cause of your latches is the fact that you have not defined all outputs for all case statements because if you do that you'd see them.
Below is a reduced example of your code

```
case(player) is
  when '0' =>
    show_out <= show;           
    ...
  when '1' =>
    show_out2 <= show;          
    ...
  when others =>
    null;
end case;
```

So when player is `0` we assign `show_out` and when it's `1` we assign `show_out2` accordingly. Now what happens with `show_out` in that case? As you might already expect, if `player` is `1` the signal `show_out` will keep it's previous value what is the same as if you write

```
case(player) is
  when '0' =>
    show_out <= show;
    show_out2 <= show_out2;
    ...
  when '1' =>
    show_out <= show_out;
    show_out2 <= show;          
    ...
  when others =>
    null;
end case;
```

And as your process is not clocked, the synthesizer creates latches.
So what you could do would be to clock the process, this way you would get ff's instead of latches.

Answer (score 1):

You need to realize that if a signal is only assigned part of the time, the synthesis software doesn't now what to do the rest of the time. So it infers latches... and latches are bad is you don't want them, because they are not synchronized to the clock and can cause glitches.

You have two options: either implement actual multiplexers, to set the output to a default state if not assigned, e.g.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

package pkg is
    type player_signals is record
        show : std_logic;
        set : std_logic;
        input : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        try : std_logic;
    end record;
end package;

LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use work.pkg.all;

entity two_player_demux is
    port (
        input : in player_signals;
        player : in std_logic;
        player0 : out player_signals;
        player1 : out player_signals);
end entity;

architecture rtl of two_player_demux is
    signal player_signals_default : player_signals := (
        show => '0',
        set => '0',
        input => (others => '0'),
        try => '0'
    );
begin
    player0 <= input when player='0' else player_signals_default;
    player1 <= input when player='1' else player_signals_default;
end architecture;
```

Or you want to remember the last value which was set on the output: implement registers. You need to add a clock in that case:

```
entity two_player_demux is
    port (
        clk : in std_logic;
        input : in player_signals;
        player : in std_logic;
        player0 : out player_signals;
        player1 : out player_signals);
end entity;

architecture rtl of two_player_demux is
begin
    clk_proc : process(clk) begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if player = '0' then
                player0 <= input;
            else -- player='1'
                player1 <= input;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```